# How to parse strange XML file with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I've got the following XML file where the same nodes are repeated within the file and I'd need to get the values/properties of 'console & int' for example.

Any idea how I could retrieve the 'config' parent for 'console & int' so that I could after get /values/property? I am having the problem that 'console' and 'int' are at the same level so I don't know:

1. How to query for 'type=console' and 'env=int' simultaneously?
2. How to get the parent once I can find those specific nodes? so can then retrieve 'values/property' after the correct 'config' parent node?

The XML we need to work with is:

```
<server>
  <propertySets>
    <config>
     <type>console</type>
     <env>int</env>
     <values>
         <property name="a">a</property>
         <property name="b">b</property>
     </values>
    </config>

    <config>
     <type>console</type>
     <env>test</env>
     <values>
         <property name="c">c</property>
         <property name="d">d</property>
     </values>
    </config>

    <config>
     <type>embedded</type>
     <env>int</env>
     <values>
         <property name="f">f</property>
         <property name="g">g</property>
     </values>
   </config>
 </propertySets>
</server>
```

Comment: Is there are root node? It is not a well-formed XML document otherwise, which makes the problem harder

Comment: Just checked, yes, those nodes are under 'server > propertySets'. I amended the XML in the post to display the whole structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xpath` is very flexible; You can do what you want directly with an XPath query:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Document.parse( File.open('configs.xml' ) )
xml.xpath('/server/propertySets/config[type="console" and env="int"]/values/property[@name="a"]').text
```

You don't need to do it all in one go. The `xpath` result at any point is everything that matches that accessor, so you can get your chosen config block like this:

```
selected_config = xml.xpath('/server/propertySets/config[type="console" and env="int"]')
```

and then fetch a value you are interested in:

```
property_a_value = selected_config.xpath('values/property[@name="a"]').text
```

The results of `xpath` keep their context within the main document, so you can even extend back up from `selected_config` to query the next sibling item etc.

Comment: Nice one, many thanks Neil!!! I didn't know you could just make this... type="console" and env="int". Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Think of the results of `search`, `xpath` and `css` like they're arrays of pointers, or double-linked lists, into the nodes in the DOM. That's why they are able to be used to look up and down in the hierarchy, and why we are able to detach them and move them around and their `children` move with them.